# D3.JS - make my links visible

Tags: graph, tree, d3.js

I want to make a graph that structures different information, a bit like "pearltrees" (http://www.pearltrees.com/).
At the moment I have elements being shown (but not yet associated with any kind of data) an I have links between them (every element is attached to the one before).
The problem is: the connections are there but nor visible.
Hint: it's not the browser, must be the code ;)
Tried a lot, searched on the internet, but now I think this problem costs me to much time, so I want to ask You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.25.0">       
     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?1.25.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?1.25.0"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
link { stroke: #999; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var w = 960,
h = 650,
nodes = [],
node,
 i = 0,
 links = [];

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);


//create force:
var force = d3.layout.force()           
.nodes(nodes)                           
.links(links)                               
.linkDistance(30)
.charge([-50])                      
.friction([0.98])   
.gravity([0.025])                       
.size([w, h]);

 //apply the force
force.on("tick", function(e) {      
    vis.selectAll("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });   
});

//add 15 objects that are connected each to the one before.
setInterval(function(){
if(i<15){ 
    nodes.push({
        size: Math.random() * 300 + 100,
        id: i
    });
    if(i!=0){
        links.push({source: nodes[i], target: nodes[i-1]});
    }
}

i = i+1;    

vis.selectAll("path")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
  .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("fill-opacity", "0.9")
  .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
  .call(force.drag);


// Restart the force layout.
force
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .start();

drawLines(); 

//enter new nodes:
node.enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);

// Exit old nodes:
node.exit().remove();
}, 1000);

function drawLines(){
lines = svg.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(links);
lines.enter().insert("svg:line", "circle.node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
    .attr("drawn", 1)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", "black");
d3.selectAll("link").style("color", "black");
}
```

This is still a set of example-code from the D3.js-examples-site, but this will be changed in further developement.

Thanks for helping.

edit: posted more code to show you how the whole script works/does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what made it, but now it's working.

Stored the nodes as well as links in one variable, because JSON refused to work, ans now it does the links as it is supposed to.

```
force
  .nodes(jsonData.nodes)
  .links(jsonData.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(jsonData.links)
.enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(jsonData.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "../img/perry_rhodan.png")
  .attr("x", -8)
  .attr("y", -8)
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 30);

node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("fill", "#aa0000")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name });

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.skill; });    

force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your **nodes** and **links** are empty arrays -- so you should not be seeing anything.

You can add objects **links** array like this:

```
var link = {};
link.source = <node obj>;
link.target = <node obj>;
links.push(link);
```

where node obj is a reference to an object in the **nodes** array.

Comment: sorry, I just posted the rest of the script to make work more easy ;) I create 15 elements in a loop and connect them each to the one before. they hang on to their targets but have no visible connections. what do I have to change to make them visible?